# could some one explain time complexity to me from this image

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, theorem-proving

could some one please explain why `n >= 1` and not `n >=0`
since `0` is also true for the below argument

[image]

Comment: I think you are bogged down by the math.  This is the crucial statement: `Therefore, any logarithmic or linear function is in O(n^2)...`  So a linear function is `O(n^2)` and so is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

n>=0 is not ok, I look up the definition in the Introduction to algorithms(CLRS), it requires n to be positive.
I think the reason is that we use big-O notation to make approximation of an algorithm, so we want input, and n=0 means no input, so we don't want to involve it in our calculation.